# Is there a ppa/repository for jmeter 3?

Tags: ubuntu, jmeter, repository

I am searching for a ppa that have the JMeter 3 releases. The actual ubuntu 17.10 release (https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/artful/universe/base/jmeter, https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=jmeter) only JMeter Version 2.13.20170723. Does anyone know a repository with the latest releases of JMeter?

My intention is not to install it by hand. I prefer a repository to get constantly updates and so on.

Answer (score 1):

JMeter is a pure Java application therefore you  therefore you don't need any repository.

1. Install Java 8 (which is a pre-requisite for JMeter 3.3)

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
   ```
2. If you have > 1 Java version you can choose the correct one using the following command:

   ```
   sudo update-alternatives --config java
   ```
3. Double check your Java installation by running the next command in the terminal

   ```
   java -version
   ```

   and make sure you have `1.8.0` in the output
4. Once done you can download the latest JMeter version like:

   ```
   wget http://www.namesdir.com/mirrors/apache//jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-3.3.tgz
   ```
5. Unpack it:

   ```
   tar xf apache-jmeter-3.3.tgz
   ```
6. And launch it:

   ```
   apache-jmeter-3.3/bin/./jmeter
   ```

References:

- [How can I install OpenJDK on Ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/759451/how-can-i-install-openjdk-on-ubuntu-16-04)
- [JMeter Installation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#install)
- [How to Get Started With JMeter: Part 1 - Installation & Test Plans](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-get-started-jmeter-part-1-installation-test-plans)

Comment: That was not my intention...I want a repository to constantly get updates. How to install it by downloading it is not the problem.

Comment: The answer doesn't respond the question

Comment: I'm also looking for a repository. I have been installing usual jmeter version through regular repository, but then I've just downloaded a new version in .tgz archive, renamed the old /usr/share/jmeter directory and moved newly downloaded unpacked apache-jmeter-5.2.1 into /usr/share/ directory renaming it to jmeter and it starts without issues with main menu icon.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is No. There's no repositories available in the public access on the Internet right now.

Similar question is asked [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/690983/how-can-i-update-jmeter-in-ubuntu/1198960#1198960).

But there's no answer you ask for, at least till now.